# Total orbital and spin angular momentum for a closed shell

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics

I read one Phys.SE question similar to mine, in
[Total angular momentum in a full shell](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96681/)
but the question was so confusing and vague. The answer, though, was helpful for me to understand a part of my question. 
It's said that the total orbital and spin angular momentum for a closed shell is zero. I understand, as explained in the link above, that paired electrons in a closed shell have zero net spin. That's because each pair has one up electron and one down. But I can't realize why this holds for total orbital angular momentum too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The total angular momentum of a closed shell is zero because for fixed $l$, we have the possible states labeled by eigenvalues of $L_i$ as $m_{l,i} = l,\dots,0,\dots,-l$ in integer steps. The sum over all $m_l$ inside a shell is always zero, so total angular momentum of a shell is zero.

This is just the generalization of the argument with "up/down" for spin, which is the case $l = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Hi, I have a question about your answer; for *any* $\ell$ the sum over the $m_{\ell}$ is always zero. So if we consider hydrogen for simplicity and $\ell = 3$ then $\sum_{-3}^{m_{\ell}=3}(\ell=3)=-3+-2+-1+0+1+2+3=0$. Clearly, this cannot be the case and I am not understanding part of your answer. I would just like to see an example where the total orbital angular momentum is non-zero in the case of an *unfilled* shell.

Comment: @BLAZE Of course, to get the total angular momentum of an unfilled shell, you only sum those $m_l$ that correspond to a *filled* state.

Comment: This shows that the z-projection $m_L$ of total orbital angular momentum (coming from the operator $L_z = \sum_{i} l_{z,i})$ is zero. But to show that total orbital angular momentum is zero, it is also necessary to show that the magnitude $\mathbf{L}^2$ is zero.