# Total orbital angular momentum of closed orbital

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

Can anyone please help me in understanding why total orbital angular momentum of a closed orbital is zero? I can understand that the z th component $L_z$ = $m_l$h/2π will be zero on summing over all indexes but not why total L will be zero.
[Total orbital and spin angular momentum for a closed shell](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195554/total-orbital-and-spin-angular-momentum-for-a-closed-shell)
This is the link of a very much similar question but it doesn't answer my doubt as it goes through z-th component of L only and not x and y components. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Closed shells have spherical symmetry so if one component of $L$ is zero they all are zero.

Comment: Can you please clarify on why it would be spherically symmetrical and hence forth the how the total orbital angular momentum is zero? Thank you.